# Problems with incoming data from multiple places where the unique ID can come in after the msg..problem

Tags: c#, events, synchronization

Been mulling and working on this last 48hrs and just not getting anywhere.  So let me jump right to the issue.

I'm working with an API.

I send a request to the API as such
http://localhost:8080/Execute....etc..etc <--- a webrequest

This in turn returns an "ID".

The API also sends via a UDP port an Order# to that ID

-So the API receives the Request and responds with an ID.

Then

-API sends an Order# it associates with that ID on a UDP port AFTER issuing the ID

However, there is no set Timing to this, it's as it comes.

Now on the other end of this is the BackEnd Server.

This is constantly sending [Msg Updates] via UDP.

So the sequence can go something like this.

I have my UDP listener configured for Port 1234.
I have my UDP Lister configured for Port 2222 <-- the back end server sending msgs

I execute via the API http://localhost:8080/execut...etc 
(String response from API server) <--- receive ID
(ms time goes by)
(UDP Port 1234) <--- Order#

[Port 2222]<--- Receives [Msg update] with Order details.

Problem is the [Msg Update] can and does come in faster than the Order# associated with the [MsgUpdate].

Currently My solution is as follows but feels very cluncky and well (You know that feeling when your code/design makes ya feel a little dirty) well that's what I'm going through now.  Here's my current way of approaching the problem.

The associations are as follows.

1 Unique ID ----> 1 OrderNumber.

Multiple OrderStates ---> 1 OrderNumber (accepted, cancelled, ....etc)

the Incoming Msg from the Server has Only the OrderNumber and no (ID) tag that you get from the API.

So here's how I'm handling it....or trying to.

And please if you guys can see a better way to do this I'm all for it I'll toss this entire garbage solution out the window in a heartbeat.

Is there a much cleaner more elegant way to accomplish this?

As you can see you can receive [Msg Updates] faster than you receive the OrderNumber, AND each Incoming [MsgUpdate] can have different states for the Order...

For example:  #1000 accepted, #1000 cancelled, #1001 Accepted, #1001 Rejected [Not enough BP], #1002 Cancelled, #1010 Partially Filled

But takeaway is that there is nothing unique about the incoming orders except the ordernumber (#1001) and that is only associated with the ID from the API you get after the execute, then have to wait for the UDP response from the API to get the orderNumber (#1001) and only then you know what that [1001] is YOUR msg. ugh......

Anyway my pseudo code to give a basic premise of what I did to attempt to address this.

```
[Client Class]

private IOrderNumberListener ordListener;
private IBackendListener _blistener;

public Client(IOrdernUmberListener ordListen, IBackendListener backListen)
{
    ordListener = ordListen;
    _blistener = backListen;

    ordListener += IncomingOrderNo;
    _blistener += ReceiveIncomingMsgsFromServer;
}

public string IncomingOrderNo(string exeord)
{
    //Deal with it

}


/// This method will recieve data for everything including things that isn't related to the ID 
private void ReceiveIncomingMsgsFromServer(object sen`enter code here`der, data)
{
    //Process Incoming data
    //So in here is a check for the OrderNumber which doesn't have the ID associated with it.  Just 
      the OrderNumber with details.

    if(data.ordernumber == this.Ordernumber)   <--- this I feel isn't all that great.  

    // QUERY the _blistener.GetOrderDetails(this.OrderNumber);

    //Deal with things here.
}


public string executeOrder(string url)
{
    webrequest..(url)...etc
}

[Back End Server Class]

//UDP Listener Configuration stuff here

......

public event EventHandler<Msg> Update;

private Dictionary<string, msgData> OrderDb = new Dictionary.....etc

private void sendUpdate(data)
{
    //raise event method etc..

}

private process packet(byte[] data)
{
    /// process data


    sendUpdate(processedData);
}

public msgData GetOrderDetails(string ordernumber)
{
    //Check db return orderdetails.
}
```

Comment: Are you only sending one request at a time or multiple requests?  Complicated communication systems usually in situations like this have a input queue where all incoming messages are place.  Then a search is performed on the query until an entire message is received.  This is similar to a TCP application where a message is broken up into datagrams with max size of 1500 bytes.  Receiver has to wait until entire message is received before processing message.  Your application is similar that you have to wait until data is received on two ports before completing processing.

Comment: @jdweng That's the fun part there is no batch order input.  Just a lot of sequential order inputs via the webrequest, then dealing with the incoming responses from different "venues".  It's be great if I could even generate the ordernumbers ahead of time so when I execute I'm ready and waiting for the [msg] from the server, BUT can't.

Comment: For a system like this to work, responses have to have an ID that corresponds to the request.  Then you have to search the input query by ID and make sure you have all the pieces for the ID.  At work we had a multi-process system like this where no ID was used and as soon as the messages got out of sync the system would fail.  The software team rewrote the code and and changed it to single process.  The new code now runs much slower because commands are run one at a time but doesn't get out of order.The right way of writing code like this is to have every request/response contain an unique ID.

Comment: @jdweng I COMPLETELY agree....unfortunately I have it's the design at work and it's not changing anytime soon....as in like Never!.  So I'm here forced to just try and figure out how to solve this.  I had a thought the other day to "Daisy Chain" the events like maybe throw everything into a separate library.  Have the ReqID (from the webrequest) sit in there, and then as it gets the OrderNumber it'll check a table/dictionary and return with what it has. (maybe if the order had 9 states it only had 4 at the time it checked) then

Comment: It'll Raise an event to the client with those 4 and as a change happens in the table again, it'll send the other 5 at which point the client "removes" the "ID" and no more events for that order....(As you can see I'm just grasping here)...

Comment: As I said the correct way of doing this is to have an incoming message queue and put all the input channels into a single queue.